# VBA/SQL ACCESS: Copy query result to a table in other access database

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

i want to copy my query results to a other Access database with
VBA-code in a module or directly with the SQL-query.

maybe my code should look like this?:

```
Sub export()
  DoCmd.CopyObject , "myquery", acQuery, "C:/...mytable//"   
  MsgBox ("Export finish!" & Date & " , " & Time)
  DoCmd.SetWarnings True
End Sub
```

Thanks for each tip!

Answer (score 0):

The below should be your code to copy a query from one access database to another...

```
DoCmd.TransferDatabase acExport, "Microsoft Access", "C:\DestTemp\Dest.mdb", acQuery, "qryInfo", "qryInfo".
```

"C:\DestTemp\Dest.mdb" -> your target database

qryInfo -> Query name in the source and then the target database accordingly...

NOTE: Both the database must be opened during this task....

Comment: till ..acQuery i understand the code.    first qryinfo is the Name of my query and the second??

Comment: the remaining things are just your query names in the source and target databases accordingly...

Comment: Both the databases do not have to be open, only the one running the code, and even at that you might get away with script, but I have not tested.

Comment: the Export runs but, if i want to open the table in the target database. i get error, because the FROM TABLE dont exist in the target database

Comment: i only want to save the results in the target database

Comment: could you please post your solution?

Comment: i had a Syntax mistake, your code was right! Do you know how to copy the result of a query into a table with vba, IN THE SAME database? only copy

Comment: I hope the below is what you are looking for...

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Add-records-to-a-table-by-using-an-append-query-98a5bd66-2190-4243-9638-8ef649cf3596

Comment: thank u for link, but i want solve this with vba, because i have a lot of queries (about 100),  its better with code as Manual i think